# Curling and Parsing URL from Fitbit API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, curl

I'm relatively new to Rails web development and coding in general. I'm currently developing a web application that should retrieve data from my Fitbit account. This is done through the Fibit API and OAuth2.0.

Essentially, here's my problem. As shown on the Fitbit tutorial website, https://dev.fitbit.com/apps/oauthinteractivetutorial, I need to get authorization from the Fitbit user. I've tried to do this using the following correct URL

```
<%= link_to "Sign in with Fitbit", "https://www.fitbit.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=228BT5&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.builtbyburton.com%2Foauth2%2Fcallback&scope=activity%20location%20profile%20sleep&expires_in=604800" %>
```

When this is called, the user is redirected to the following URL as expected:

```
http://www.builtbyburton.com/oauth2/callback?code=1093d4dc25f0c61acbbf8128a9247b0efd448c35#_=_
```

Currently, I need to capture the segment of the URL from the `code=` to `#_=_` This segment then needs to be parsed. I've tried to do it using an embedded curl as shown:

```
<pre class="embedcurl">curl -X POST -i -H 'Authorization: Basic MjI4QlQ1OmU4OWFkZWJmYTUzNTU1MGMyNGUyNjdhOWRjM2MxNzIy' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -d "clientId=228BT5" -d "grant_type=authorization_code" -d "redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.builtbyburton.com%2Foauth2%2Fcallback" -d "code=1093d4dc25f0c61acbbf8128a9247b0efd448c35" https://api.fitbit.com/oauth2/token</pre>
```

From there, I need to parse the response which will allow me to make requests. Overall, I'm just not sure how to get from the authorization link to making a request using an OAuth2.0 Access Token. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Fitbit docs](https://dev.fitbit.com/docs/oauth2/):

> Fitbit uses OAuth 2.0 for user authorization and API authentication.
>   The OAuth 2.0 framework requires your application to obtain an Access
>   Token when the Fitbit user authorizes your app to access their data.
>   The Access Token is used for making HTTP request to the Fitbit API.
>
> You don't need a Fitbit-specific library to use the Fitbit Web API.
>   Instead, **we recommend that you use the best OAuth 2.0 or HTTP client
>   library available for your platform**. If you don't have a favorite
>   OAuth 2.0 or HTTP library yet, we've listed some here

There's nothing listed for ruby, but if you google **rails oauth2**, the first hit is:

https://github.com/intridea/oauth2

The example there looks pretty straightforward:

```
gem install oauth2
```

The rails equivalent would be to add the following to your Gemfile:

```
gem oauth2
```

And here's the example code:

```
client = OAuth2::Client.new('client_id', 'client_secret', :site => 'https://example.org')

client.auth_code.authorize_url(:redirect_uri => 'http://localhost:8080/oauth2/callback')
# => "https://example.org/oauth/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=client_id&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/oauth2/callback"

token = client.auth_code.get_token('authorization_code_value', :redirect_uri => 'http://localhost:8080/oauth2/callback', :headers => {'Authorization' => 'Basic some_password'})
response = token.get('/api/resource', :params => { 'query_foo' => 'bar' })
response.class.name
# => OAuth2::Response
```

---

Original answer:

> I've tried to do it using an embedded curl as shown:

You can't have arbitrary code in an html file.  Rails uses something called ERB(or another parsing engine of your choice) to parse pages like `page1.html.erb` that are located in specfic directories in your rails project--but then you have to follow the rules of ERB parsing.  You *can* make ERB execute arbitrary ruby code, but a `bash` command, like `curl` isn't even ruby code--it's `bash` code.

> ```
> http://www.builtbyburton.com/oauth2/callback?code=1093d4dc25f0c61acbbf8128a9247b0efd448c35#_=_
> ```
>
> Currently, I need to capture the segment of the URL from the code = to
>   #_=_

That part of the url is known as the *query* string.  You can get it like this:

```
require 'uri'

url = 'http://www.builtbyburton.com/oauth2/callback?code=1093d4dc25f0c61acbbf8128a9247b0efd448c35#_=_'

obj = URI(url)
query_str = obj.query
puts query_str

--output:--
code=1093d4dc25f0c61acbbf8128a9247b0efd448c35
```

You can get just the authorization code like this:

```
name, value = query_str.split '='
puts value

--output:--
1093d4dc25f0c61acbbf8128a9247b0efd448c35
```